# Can a Graph be Proven to be Directional?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, eulerian-path

Here's a line from my textbook that I'm having trouble understanding:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. If $G$ is
> undirected then then $m\leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, and if $G$ is directed,
> then $m\leq n(n-1)$

Does this mean that if the second condition holds then the graph must be directed even if it was not specified as such?

If this is not the case but the second condition still holds for $G$, can we at least say that $G$ has an Eulerian Cycle if $m$ is even, since we know that when $G$ is directed then:
$$\sum_{v \in G}\mathrm{indeg(v)} = \sum_{v \in G}\mathrm{outdeg(v)}=m$$
and this would indicate that $G$ has an even degree?

Comment: Almost. If $m\le\frac{n(n-1)}2$, then it could be either. But if $\frac{n(n-1)}2<m\le n(n-1)$, then it must be directed. Notice that this isn't as simple as saying "the second condition holds", because the first and second conditions are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: It would be a bizarre setting in which you were using this to prove that a graph was directed; usually, you know this long before you know how many edges it has. It's like saying "a human has at most $2$ legs and a chair has at most $4$; based on the observation that the entity had $3$ or more legs, we conclude that it's a chair". Technically valid, but...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Well the question I'm trying to answer is something like: you have a graph G where the sum of the degrees of each vertex is 24 and the number of vertices is 12 what else can we say about the graph. I just wanted to make my question more general.

Comment: To say an undirected graph has an Eulerian cycle, we need it connected and every vertex to have even degree.  If all you know about is the sum of the degrees, you have very little information about the individual degrees.